# Unexpected "," from StreamReader to StreamWriter

Tags: c#, logic

I've tried a lot of things as well as research and asking friends, but can't seem to write a second line without a "," replacing the line. All I'd to do is have a single line for each item read in a separate file.

Each read file has several of these items:

```
2/20/2014 7:33:10 AM
OPERATOR: jason
FILE: C:\ax14\Setups\000062363106RH.prt
UNITS: english
TEST RESULT: Pass

    CHANNEL 1
        TEST TYPE: VELOCITY
        RESULT:  Pass
        UPPER LIMIT: 0.2260
        LOWER LIMIT: 0.2220
        MAX THICKNESS: 2.0110
        MIN THICKNESS: 1.0110
        MEASURED VELOCITY: 0.2225
        MEASURED THICKNESS: 1.5215
```

Id like to have the date and velocity line in one line like this:
"2/20/2014 7:33:10 AM, MEASURED VELOCITY: 0.2225"

and this is my problem

```
2/20/2014 7:33:10 AM,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,   MEASURED VELOCITY: 0.2225
,
2/20/2014 7:52:28 AM,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,
,   MEASURED VELOCITY: 0.2224
,
2/20/2014 7:58:46 AM,
```

---

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace conApp
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String line;
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\writetest\\writetest.txt"))
                {
                    string mydirpath = "C:\\chat\\";

                    string[] txtFileList = Directory.GetFiles(mydirpath, "*.txt");

                    foreach (string txtName in txtFileList)
                    {
                        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(txtName);

                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                {
                                    String spart = ".prt";
                                    String sam = " AM";
                                    String spm = " PM";
                                    String sresult = "TEST RESULT: ";
                                    String svelocity = "MEASURED VELOCITY: ";
                                    String part = "";
                                    String date = "";
                                    String result = "";
                                    String velocity = "";
                                    // sw.WriteLine(line);

                                    if (line.Contains(sam))
                                    {
                                        date = line;
                                    }

                                    if (line.Contains(spm))
                                    {
                                        date = line;
                                    }

                                    if (line.Contains(spart))
                                    {
                                        part = line;
                                    }

                                    if (line.Contains(sresult))
                                    {
                                        result = line;
                                    }

                                    if (line.Contains(svelocity))
                                    {
                                        velocity = line;
                                    }
                                    int I = 2;
                                    string[] x = new string[I];
                                    x[0] = date;
                                    x[1] = velocity;

                                    sw.WriteLine(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
                                }


                            }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for the full Main() trying to use as much from your code as possible. Declaring your vars outside the `while` statement you don't need to make it null.

**EDIT**- I forgot you said:

> Each read file has several of these items

So added a few lines to handle that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line;
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\writetest\\writetest.txt"))
        {
            string mydirpath = "C:\\chat\\";

            string[] txtFileList = Directory.GetFiles(mydirpath, "*.txt");

            foreach (string txtName in txtFileList)
            {
                string spart = ".prt";
                string sam = " AM";
                string spm = " PM";
                string sresult = "TEST RESULT: ";
                string svelocity = "MEASURED VELOCITY: ";
                string part = string.Empty;
                string date = string.Empty;
                string result = string.Empty;
                string velocity = string.Empty;

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Trim().Length != 0)
                        {
                            if (line.Contains(sam) || line.Contains(spm))
                            {
                                // Every new date means a new record. If you already have data for a record, first write it.
                                if (date != string.Empty && velocity != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    int I = 2;
                                    string[] x = new string[I];
                                    x[0] = date;
                                    x[1] = velocity;
                                    sw.WriteLine(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
                                }
                                // Then reset data to prepare it for a new record
                                part = string.Empty;
                                result = string.Empty;
                                velocity = string.Empty;
                                date = line;
                            }

                            if (line.Contains(spart))
                            {
                                part = line;
                            }

                            if (line.Contains(sresult))
                            {
                                result = line;
                            }

                            if (line.Contains(svelocity))
                            {
                                velocity = line;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // After last record you still have some data to write
                if (date != string.Empty && velocity != string.Empty)
                {
                    int I = 2;
                    string[] x = new string[I];
                    x[0] = date;
                    x[1] = velocity;
                    sw.WriteLine(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I dont have the 4.0 VS framework able to use the method IsNullOrWhiteSpace,

Comment: @TheodoreCross Replaced IsNullOrWhiteSpace by equivalent code valid since .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Only write the line once you have both values:
Then reset both values to null.

```
sw.WriteLine(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
```

Becomes:

```
if ( !String.IsNullOrWhitespace( date) && !String.IsNullOrWhitespace( velocity )
{
  sw.WriteLine(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
  date = null;
  velocity = null;
}
```

As Blas mentioned you also need to move the variables outside the while statement:

```
String result = "";
String velocity = "";
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Comment: The problem is that you are writing a line every time you get go through the loop, e.g. you are writing one line for every line in you original file.

Comment: NOTE: edited - resetting date and velocity should happen inside the if statement.

Comment: Ok to reset date and velocity inside the if statement, but also it's needed to initialize these 2 vars outside the while statement.

Comment: He should also dispose the `StreamReader` by using a `using` statement, or calling `Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex Pattern to Achieve your goal :

```
(^.*?(?:AM|PM).*?)\r?\n.*(MEASURED VELOCITY:.*?$).*
```

And here's the code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\writetest\\writetest.txt"))
{
    string mydirpath = "C:\\chat\\";

    string[] txtFileList = Directory.GetFiles(mydirpath, "*.txt");

    Regex regex = new Regex("(^.*?(?:AM|PM).*?)\r?\n.*(MEASURED VELOCITY:.*?$).*",
        RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (string txtName in txtFileList)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(txtName))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sw.WriteLine(regex.Replace(text, "$1, $2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output for given file example:

> 2/20/2014 7:33:10 AM, MEASURED VELOCITY: 0.2225